# is there a way to associate and view a repo description in vsts?

Tags: git, azure-devops

Is there a way to associate and view a repo description in vsts?

For example, I'm creating some supporting repos for a primary repo and I would prefer if other devs could view repo descriptions as opposed to having extra verbose names for the supporting repos.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue by Daniel's answer? any update?

Answer (score 0):

Add a `README.MD` file to the repo root. The contents of that file will be displayed on a README tab, right next to "Contents" and "History".